# Как подогнать размер QTextEdit под размер родительского блока в PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Делаю программу в PyQt5. Имеется следующий код (некоторые части кода опущены):

```
class CreateFrames(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initFr()

    def initFr(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        topright = QFrame(self)
        topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        topleft = QFrame(self)
        topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        bottom = QFrame(self)
        bottom.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        topright.resize(100, 200)

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
        splitter1.addWidget(topright)
        splitter1.resize(100,100)
        splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter2.addWidget(bottom)
        hbox.addWidget(splitter2)
        
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(topright)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
```

Необходимо сделать, чтобы textEdit заполнял весь фрейм topright и автоматически подгонялся по его размерам.

Пробовал для родителя задавать:

```
framesheet = "position:relative"
topright.setStyleSheet(framesheet)
```

А для блока textEdit:

```
sheet = "height:100%; width:100%; position:absolution"
self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(sheet)
```

Всё тщетно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Интересная, конечно, идея размер через QSS устанавливать, но явно не то :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для указания правил автоматического размера, нужно использовать [Size Policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum).

У виджетов есть соответствующий метод [setSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1)

Попробуйте:

```
self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

---

Воссоздаю пример автора с сплиттерами, но без size policy, т.к. не похоже что оно нужно:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QSplitter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit('text_edit')
        self.plain_text_edit = QPlainTextEdit('text_edit')
        self.text_edit_log = QTextEdit('text_edit_log')

        h_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        h_splitter.addWidget(self.text_edit)
        h_splitter.addWidget(self.plain_text_edit)

        v_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        v_splitter.addWidget(h_splitter)
        v_splitter.addWidget(self.text_edit_log)

        self.setCentralWidget(v_splitter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё почему-то остаётся без изменений, текстовое поле так же в углу. Может, конечно я что-то не понимаю...

Comment: @serkomma, `self.textEdit` добавили на какой-нибудь layout?

Comment: Добавил такое: qhbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(topright)
        self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        qhbox.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.setLayout(qhbox) Видимо не правильно

Comment: @serkomma А что неправильно? Вроде бы по коду у вас должно было получиться. Добавил пример

Comment: @serkomma наверное, не `self.setLayout(qhbox)`, а `topright.setLayout(qhbox)`. Это ведь компоновщик не главного виджета, а фрейма `topright`. И при создании `QHBoxLayout`, `QTextEdit` не надо указывать родителя, а то путаница начинается. `setSizePolicy` можно и не указывать.

Comment: @mkkik Да, спасибо вам, проблема решилась. Остался лишь маленький косяк - текстовое поле не растягивается до границ фрейма, оставляя серую полосу вокруг, т.е. получается размер поля немного меньше размера родительского фрейма

Comment: Это `margins` - отступы. Настраивается так: `qhbox.setContentsMargins(QMargins())` - нулевые отступы со всех сторон.

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем вручную писать интерфейс, если его можно в Дизайнере накидать быстро, а потом уже править кодом, где надо. Может я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @ФилиппБондарев, полезно и через дизайнер делать, и уметь вручную. Для простых форм заморачиваться с `ui` не охото, да и если делать канонично, тогда: создаем `widget.ui` файл с формой, на его основе генерируем `widget_ui.py` файл, создаем `widget.py`, который сохраняет в себе ссылку на `widget_ui.py` в поле `ui`. Такая схема для маленьких форм просто чудовищная :) И такая схема работает и в реализации на с++, только `Qt Creator` незаметно сгенерирует `widget_ui.cpp`, а для питона нужно вызывать определенную утилиту